# Как сделать замену текста на другой и обратно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется уже готовая функция для отключения определенных полей при выборе input.
[Залил код и скрипт на playcode.io](https://playcode.io/465126?tabs=index.html,preview)

Каким образом можно заменить текст на другой при нажатии на определенное поле и вернуть его обратно при нажатии на другие поля?

В частности нужно заменить текст:

> Наличными на Наличными курьеру
>
> Пластиковой картой на Картой онлайн

Только при нажатии на:

> Курьер (собственная курьерская служба) и Срочный курьер (собственная
>   курьерская служба)

UPD 24.10.19

```
const valuesShow = [ 12,30,55,70,75,299,709,759,769,779  ];
$('#sample_form_deliv').change(function({ target: { value } }) {
$('#sample_form_pay .input-label:eq(1)').toggle(valuesShow.includes(+value));

var PayTextForm = $('#sample_form_pay');
    if (this.change) {
var replaced = PayTextForm.html().replace(/Наличными/gi, 'Наличными курьеру');
var replaced = PayTextForm.html().replace(/Пластиковой картой/gi, 'Картой онлайн');
PayTextForm.html(replaced);
    } else {
var replaced = PayTextForm.html().replace(/Наличными курьеру/gi, 'Наличными');
var replaced = PayTextForm.html().replace(/Картой онлайн/gi, 'Пластиковой картой');
    PayTextForm.html(replaced);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот решение с той версткой, которую ты закинул в песочницу.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#sample_form_deliv');
const paymentOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#sample_form_pay > fieldset > label');
const deliveryOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#sample_form_deliv > fieldset > label > input');
form.addEventListener('change', changePaymentMethods);

function changePaymentMethods(e) {
  const standartMethods =
    (e.target !== deliveryOptions[0]) &&
    (e.target !== deliveryOptions[2])

  setPaymentOptions(standartMethods);
}

function setPaymentOptions(isStandart) {
  paymentOptions[0].removeChild(paymentOptions[0].lastChild);
  paymentOptions[2].removeChild(paymentOptions[2].lastChild);

  if (isStandart) {
    paymentOptions[0].append('Наличными');
    paymentOptions[1].style.display = 'block';
    paymentOptions[2].append('Пластиковой картой');
  } else {
    paymentOptions[0].append('Наличными курьеру');
    paymentOptions[1].style.display = 'none';
    paymentOptions[2].append('Картой онлайн');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

img {
  width: 56px;
  height: 48px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: 26px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample_form_deliv" class="cart_delivery b-field clearfix">
  <fieldset required="" class="b-checkbox-group">
    <legend class="p_header bold">Способ доставки:</legend>
    <label class="input-label left">   
    <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" data-est-delivery=" При заказе до 12:00: в день заказа. Иначе на следующий день" data-rate="500" value="56" name="sample_form_deliv">
      <span></span>   Курьер (собственная курьерская служба) (500 ₽)  </label>
    <label class="input-label left">   
       <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" data-est-delivery="В определённые часы, в остальные часы в утренние часы работы ругие условия (прописать)" data-rate="0" value="55" name="sample_form_deliv">
       <span></span>   Самовывоз из центрального магазина (0 ₽)  </label>
    <label class="input-label left">   
         <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" data-est-delivery=" В день заказа " data-rate="750" value="57" name="sample_form_deliv">
       <span></span>   Срочный курьер (собственная курьерская служба) (750 ₽)  </label>
    <label class="input-label left">   
         <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" data-est-delivery="Срок доставки 0 - 7" data-rate="1980" value="709" name="sample_form_deliv">
       <span></span>   Почта РФ - Посылка (1980 ₽)  </label>
    <label class="input-label left">   
         <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" data-rate="380" value="759" name="sample_form_deliv">
       <span></span>   Курьер (СДЭК|Посылка) (380 ₽)  </label>
    <label class="input-label left">   
         <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" value="75" name="sample_form_deliv">
       <span></span>   Пункты самовывоза (СДЭК|Посылка)  </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="sample_form_pay" class="cart_money b-field clearfix" style="display: block;">
  <fieldset class="b-checkbox-group">
    <legend class="p_header bold">Оплата:</legend>
    <label class="input-label left">
   <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" value="5" name="sample_form_pay">
      <span></span>Наличными
  </label>
    <label class="input-label left b-inline-checkbox">
   <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" value="9" name="sample_form_pay">
    <span></span>Перевод на карту
  </label>
    <label class="input-label left b-inline-checkbox">
   <input class="b-check-box" type="radio" value="14" name="sample_form_pay">
      <span></span>Пластиковой картой
  </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: @I'msosorry только смотри, что если количество пунктов изменится или в этот label в конец добавится ещё что либо, нужно будет все вручную поправлять.

Comment: Это понятно) до этого код был аналогичен, приходилось добавлять (удалять) пункты на изменение

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно понял. Такое решение должно помочь.

JQuery:

```
$('input[type=radio].Добавить_класс_проверяемого_элемента').change(function() {
  $(".клас_текста(лэйбла)_который_нужно_скрывать").toggleClass('show');
});
```

CSS:

```
.клас_текста(лэйбла)_который_нужно_скрывать{
  display:none;
}
.клас_текста(лэйбла)_который_нужно_скрывать.show{
  display:block
}
```

Comment: нужно менять текст, скрытие элемента уже присутствует в коде

Answer (score 0):

**Осторожно**, это может быть полнейшая дичь. Иногда пишешь такой, изобретаешь что-то, а это всё можно сделать одной строчкой кода )

```js
const paymentOptionOne = document.querySelector('#payment-option-1');
const paymentOptionTwo = document.querySelector('#payment-option-2');
const paymentOptionThree = document.querySelector('#payment-option-3');

const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('change', changePaymentMethods);

function changePaymentMethods(e) {
  if(e.target.name !== 'payment-method') {
    const standartMethods = true;

    if (e.target.id === 'delivery-option-1' || e.target.id === 'delivery-option-3') {
      setPaymentOptions(!standartMethods);
    } else {
      setPaymentOptions(standartMethods);
    }
  }
}

function setPaymentOptions(isStandart) {
  if (isStandart) {
    paymentOptionOne.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Наличными';
    paymentOptionTwo.parentNode.classList.remove('hidden');
    paymentOptionThree.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Пластиковой картой';
  } else {
    paymentOptionOne.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Наличными курьеру';
    paymentOptionTwo.parentNode.classList.add('hidden');
    paymentOptionThree.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Картой онлайн';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

input {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Способ доставки:</legend>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="delivery-option-1" name="delivery-method">
        <label for="delivery-option-1">Курьер (собственная курьерская служба) (500 ₽)</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="delivery-option-2" name="delivery-method">
        <label for="delivery-option-2">Самовывоз из центрального магазина (0 ₽)</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="delivery-option-3" name="delivery-method">
        <label for="delivery-option-3">Срочный курьер (собственная курьерская служба) (750 ₽)</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="delivery-option-4" name="delivery-method">
        <label for="delivery-option-4">Почта РФ - Посылка (1980 ₽)</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="delivery-option-5" name="delivery-method">
        <label for="delivery-option-5">Курьер (СДЭК|Посылка) (380 ₽)</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="delivery-option-6" name="delivery-method">
        <label for="delivery-option-6">Пункты самовывоза (СДЭК|Посылка)</label>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Оплата:</legend>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="payment-option-1" name="payment-method">
        <label for="payment-option-1">Наличными</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="payment-option-2" name="payment-method">
        <label for="payment-option-2">Перевод на карту</label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="payment-option-3" name="payment-method">
        <label for="payment-option-3">Пластиковой картой</label>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `const standartMethods = (e.target.name !== 'payment-method') && (e.target.id !== 'delivery-option-1') && (e.target.id !== 'delivery-option-3')` — Ну как минимум логические выражения и без if возвращают true или false... можно в одну строчку прямо прописать условие в переменную. А дальше уже без всяких if, сразу вызвать `setPaymentOptions(standartMethods);` уже с готовым значением)

Comment: все бы ничего, но форма генерируется из разных файлов, в том числе и из БД, в основном пару-тройку js, менять сам html нет возможности, потому решение должно быть только на уровне js (3 вечер сижу туплю)

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать в том же условии, где меняется отображение второго пункта оплаты; если нажато на определенные поля, то прячется. Вот хочется сюда подвязать if else и отслеживать нажатия. Есть код, но он не работает, никак не допру как правильно это все дело оформить.